# Generator function with yields

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux, redux-saga

I'm trying to do a generator function with yield inside a Redux saga.
I'm trying to get a value from my endpoint ind function g1 by calling function g2. Don't know id this is the right way to do it. I only want to get data from my endpoint if isTranslatable is true.
But fore some reason I get a response undefined. What am I missing. And yes I'm new at this.

service file

```
export const fetchEnglishFilterValue = async (
  countrySelectorCountry: string,
  selectedFilter: string,
  selectedFilterValue: string,
): Promise<Response> => {
  const url = `${DONORS_SERVICE_URL}/api/donors/translate/${countrySelectorCountry}/${selectedFilter}/${selectedFilterValue}`;
  return get(url);
};
```

saga file

```
export function* g1() {
  const englishFilterValue = g2(selectedFilter.key, selectedFilter.value);
  console.log(isTranslatable ? englishFilterValue : "normal value");
  console.log(englishFilterValue.next().value);
}

export function* g2(filterKey: string, filterValue: string) {
  try {
    const response: Response = yield call(fetchEnglishFilterValue, appSettings.language, filterKey, filterValue);
    console.log("response: ", response);
    const data: string = yield call([response, response.json]);
    console.log("data: ", data);
    return data;
  } catch {
    error(`Getting english filter value for datalayer. countrySelectorCountry: ${appSettings.language}, selectedFilter: ${filterKey}, selectedFilterValue: ${filterValue}`);
    return undefined;
  }
}
```

Comment: `const response: Response = yield` response will contain the value that you pass here to next(): `console.log(g.next().value);` [MDN yield](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield#syntax)

Comment: I get this in return on my console.log :/
done: false
value: {@@redux-saga/IO: true, combinator: false, type: "CALL", payload: {…}}

Comment: That would be in the console when you do `console.log(g.next())` , not when you do `console.log(g.next().value)`. The value is what `call` returns. So is what `call` returns not what you expected?

Comment: console.log(g.next().value); gived me {@@redux-saga/IO: true, combinator: false, type: "CALL", payload: {…}}

Was hoping to get my endpoint value.

Comment: It does not even trigger my fetchEnglishFilterValue function for som reason.

Comment: @ComCool which of these is registered with redux-saga ?

Comment: function* g1 is and the code inside is running fine on thhe website. I just need to get some async data and yield until I have the response data.