# Yield call not executing or?

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux, redux-saga

I'm trying to fetch some data from a endpoint. But when i console.log my response i get undefined. And when I run console.log(g.next().value) I get this in the console {@@redux-saga/IO: true, combinator: false, type: "CALL", payload: {…}}. Is the Yield call not executing or?

```
export function* g2(filterKey: string, filterValue: string) {
  try {
    const response: Response = yield call(fetchEnglishFilterValue, appSettings.language, filterKey, filterValue);
    console.log("response: ", response);
    const data: string = yield call([response, response.json]);
    console.log("data: ", data);
    return data;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

Comment: Please may you share how the generator is being used?

Comment: Yes, I have another post over here with all the code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68452501/generator-function-with-yields?noredirect=1#comment120977181_68452501

Comment: As, effectively, a repost of your previous question, I've voted to close as a dupe. [Generator function with yields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68452501/generator-function-with-yields)